# Horizontal list view in vertical scroll view in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, vertical-scrolling, horizontallist

I need to implement application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphonso.pulse

what i tried is,

```
   I think they should done through horizontalscrollview/horizontallistview.
   So i integrate horizontal listview through this sample,
```

https://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

what i need is,

- I need to integrate horizontal listview inside the vertical listview
- I should know how they integrate this idea

Any help should be appreciable.Thanks

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late but you can use this.. https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- First row -->
    <HorizontalScrollView>
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Items of this row -->
      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You will need to set appropriate layout attributes and you might want to add titles to the rows. If you have a variable number of rows, you can create them programmatically.

Comment: still_learning ya right but it should be static.I need it in dynamic manner then how to do that?

Comment: @PalPandi You can inflate the rows from an additional XML resource, add them to the outer `LinearLayout` and then add items to the inner `LinearLayout`. You could also use `ListView`s instead of the `LinearLayout`s (horizontal `ListView`s are still a pain) and add items to them.